# Can I get a javascript object property name that starts with a number?

Tags: javascript, key

```
var myObj = {"suppliers":[{"name":"supplier1","12m":"0.08","24m":"0.06"}]};

alert(myObj.suppliers[0].12m);
```

Is there a different way to get this property, or should I just not use a key that starts with a number?

Comment: BTW, this is not JSON...it is an object, technically speaking.

Comment: @NeXXeuS Could you clarify that commment? I thought Javascript Object Notation was the way objects were defined. Are these terms not  synonymous? Thanks

Comment: In essence, they are the same, but in javascript you call them objects. Plus, in JSON all keys have to be qouted: `{ "key":123 }`.

Comment: @NeXXuS My Object is declared using 'javascript object notation' is it not? All my keys have double quotes, do they not? I'm not seeing the distinction you are making.

Comment: @bodine: I like [this explanation](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).  It's just the context in which you're using the object notation.

Comment: @Cheran S Okay, this makes sense. In my actual code, the string I'm providing to myObj is coming from an ajax call, though that was not pertinent to my question. Thank you for clearing this up. I'm still not sure why this turned into a discussion of the JSON specification. The tag is appropriate to the question.

Comment: @mattsven JSON is an object literal expressed as a string. Stands for JavaScript Object Notation. They are literally one in the same.

Comment: JSON is a data format based on JavaScript literal format. Unless it is encoded as a string, if "JSON" is in a JavaScript file then it is just JavaScript literals.

Comment: Related: [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](/q/4968406/4642212).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use the following syntax to do what you describe using **bracket notation**:

```
myObject["myProperty"]
```

Bracket notation differs from **dot notation** (e.g. `myObject.myProperty`) in that it can be used to access properties whose names are illegal. Illegal  meaning that with dot notation, you're limited to using property names that are alphanumeric (plus the underscore `_` and dollar sign `$`), and don't begin with a number. Bracket notation allows us to use a string to access a property and bypass this.

```
myObject.1 // fails, properties cannot begin with numbers
myObject.& // fails, properties must be alphanumeric (or $ or _)

myObject["1"] // succeeds
myObject["&"] // succeeds
```

This also means we can use string variables to look up and set properties on objects:

```
var myEdgyPropertyName = "||~~(_o__o_)~~||";

myEdgyObject[myEdgyPropertyName] = "who's there?";

myEdgyObject[myEdgyPropertyName] // "who's there?";
```

You can read more about dot and bracket notation [here, on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use bracket syntax:

`alert(myObj.suppliers[0]["12m"]);`

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variables)

> A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or
>   dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9).
>   Because JavaScript is case sensitive, letters include the characters
>   "A" through "Z" (uppercase) and the characters "a" through "z"
>   (lowercase).