# How to find value in JSON by specify variable with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this simple JSON

```
{"places" : {
    "home" : {
        "1": "red"
    }
}}
```

I need to get `1` value depend on some variable which is my body class. Body class is changable. So this is my script:

```
(function(){    
    var bodyClass = $('body').attr('class');
    function getPlaceValue(){
        return $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
            var placeValue;
            placeValue = data.places.bodyClass.1;
            return placeValue;
        });
    }

    getPlaceValue().done(function(placeValue){
        console.log(placeValue);
    });
}).call(this);
```

I have respond that `1` value is undefined. What is wrong, is there a possible to do this?

Comment: `data.places[bodyClass][1]`.  Also I don't think you can `return placeValue;` from inside your callback.

Comment: .getjson is non-blocking. it'll return immediately **BEFORE** the ajax call ever has a chance to even get out the door or produce any results. Your `return placeValue` will have nowhere to return TO.

Comment: Possible duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809790/can-i-get-a-javascript-object-property-name-that-starts-with-a-number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define `bodyClass` as variable:

```
var bodyClass = $('body').attr('class');
```

... but then try to read a literal `bodyClass` property, which of course does not exist:

```
placeValue = data.places.bodyClass.1;
```

Additionally, [you cannot use the dot syntax to access the `1` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects):

> An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or
>   anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty
>   string. However, any property name that is not a valid JavaScript
>   identifier (for example, a property name that has a space or a hyphen,
>   or that starts with a number) can only be accessed using the square
>   bracket notation. This notation is also very useful when property
>   names are to be dynamically determined (when the property name is not
>   determined until runtime)

I suppose you meant this:

```
placeValue = data.places[bodyClass][1];
```

Comment: Also, `[1]`, not `.1` :-P

Comment: still have undefined `1`

Comment: @RocketHazmat - Correct, sorry for overlooking that. I've added proper reference.

Comment: how can i get browser as a value not as a object? now from `data.places[bodyClass]` i have an object

Comment: @Lukas - Yes, `data.places[bodyClass][1]` is a string and `data.places[bodyClass]` is an object. What do you want it to be?

Comment: simple value, that can i use as literal element in LowerCase

Comment: @Lukas - Well, if that's what you really really want, `data.places[bodyClass] = data.places[bodyClass][1]` should possibly work. I suggest you don't do it.