# How to access Json Data?

Tags: javascript, json

Can anybody help me to get data from the json below.I have get a json data in the format below and in this json you can see that there is "{0}" in each record.So my question is how i can get data from this format or is there any way to remove "{0}" from the json.

```
[{
    "ChkValue": "ChkValue",
    "Description": "Description",
    "Mode": "Mode"
}, {
    "0": {
        "ChkValue": "false",
        "Description": "Made sure guards are in place on machine",
        "Mode": "Eliminate"
    }
}, {
    "0": {
        "ChkValue": "false",
        "Description": "Use Liveguard at electrical source2",
        "Mode": "Isolate"
    }
}, {
    "0": {
        "ChkValue": "false",
        "Description": "Wear ear-muffs when using machine",
        "Mode": "Isolate"
    }
}]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I get a javascript object property name that starts with a number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809790/can-i-get-a-javascript-object-property-name-that-starts-with-a-number)

Comment: Did you try using JSON parsing functions? What happened when you did? where exactly did you get stuck?

Answer (score 3):

This is a basic javascript object traversal problem. 
To access the data inside the second object (that says "Made sure guards are in place..."), you would do:

```
jsonObj[1]["0"].Description
```

Comment: To supplement with other answers: `var jsonObj = JSON.parse("[The data in the example]");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function to work with it in JS.

Answer (score 0):

user [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to iterate over JSON

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yashhy/NMA6y/)**

```
var a = '[{"ChkValue":"ChkValue","Description":"Description","Mode":"Mode"},{"0":{"ChkValue":"false","Description":"Made sure guards are in place on machine","Mode":"Eliminate"}},{"0":{"ChkValue":"false","Description":"Use Liveguard at electrical source2","Mode":"Isolate"}},{"0":{"ChkValue":"false","Description":"Wear ear-muffs when using machine","Mode":"Isolate"}}]';
var b = JSON.parse(a);
for(var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    if(typeof b[i]["0"] != "undefined") {
        console.log(b[i]["0"].ChkValue);
        console.log(b[i]["0"].Description);
        console.log(b[i]["0"].Mode);
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to get it server side

Comment: to get this data to the server side you need AJAX https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX and your question was only about retrieving the data, that too tagged with `javascript`

Answer (score 0):

Use list[index][0]

```
var list = [
  {
      "ChkValue": "ChkValue",
      "Description":"Description",
      "Mode":"Mode"
  },
  {
      "0": {
          "ChkValue":"false",
          "Description":"Made sure guards are in place on machine",
          "Mode":"Eliminate"
      }
  }, 
  {
      "0": {
          "ChkValue":"false",
          "Description":"Use Liveguard at electrical source2",
          "Mode":"Isolate"
      }
  },
  {
      "0": {
          "ChkValue":"false","Description":"Wear ear-muffs when using machine",
          "Mode":"Isolate"
      }
  }
];

console.log(list[1][0].ChkValue); // get "false"
```

Comment: I need to access this data on server side.Is there any way to remove 0 from json data.