# unexpected token: numeric literal

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get firebase data and create table.But I get error "numeric literal".I already check other topics.How can I change my key names "0,1,2" if reason of this.

Here is my firebase structure.

[image: Screenshot-2019-01-15-Volkan-Database-Firebase-console.png]

This my work scheme.If you may need some more info.

[image: workscheme.png]

1 There is no problem there.Only issue it's display 0,1,2 to keys.

```
var table = document.getElementById("trade-history-follower"),
    cells = [2,3,4],
    row = 0,
    result = [];

while (table.rows[row]) {
    result.push(cells.map(cell => table.rows[row].cells[cell].innerText));
    row++;
}




var saveData = (function () {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    return function (data, fileName) {
        var json = JSON.stringify(data),
            blob = new Blob([json], {type: "octet/stream"}),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
}());

var data = new_jsonstr;
fileName = "dom.json";

saveData(data, fileName);
```

2 Firebase

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON( "http://olayufku.info/dom.json", function( data ) {
            var database = firebase.database();
            database.ref('orders').set(data);
        });
    });
```

3 Get from Firebase

```
<html>

  <head>
      <title>FIREBASE</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>

  <body>

    <table style="width:100%" id="ex-table">
        <tr id="tr">
            <th>value0</th>
            <th>value1:</th>
            <th>value2:</th>

    </table>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.7.0/firebase.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        // Initialize Firebase 
        var config = {
            apiKey: "....-vHIvQVk",
            authDomain: "......firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://...firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "....",
            storageBucket: "",
            messagingSenderId: "......"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        var database = firebase.database();
        database.ref("orders").once('value', function (snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                var content = '';
                snapshot.forEach(function (data) {
                    var val = data.val();
                    content += '<tr>';
                    content += '<td>' + val.0 + '</td>';
                    content += '<td>' + val.1 + '</td>';
                    content += '<td>' + val.2 + '</td>';
                    content += '</tr>';
                });
                $('#ex-table').append(content);
            }
        });

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Enclose the numeric literals with brackets, and remove the dot (`val[0]` etc.).

Comment: So `val.0` -> `val["0"]`.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809790/can-i-get-a-javascript-object-property-name-that-starts-with-a-number

Comment: Yes this solve my problem.Thank you.But I don't get to how I change 0,1.2 keys while generate json.(First code my message).