# Parsing JSON in SQL Server with JSON attribute having a number in its name

Tags: json, sql-server

I am trying to parse a JSON file that is stored in a column of a SQL server table. I am using the `JSON_VALUE` function. But this function does not like it that the attribute (called 6Months) has a number in its name. And it is giving me an error for that reason. Is there a way to force the function read the file? Please see query and error message below. I greatly appreciate any help.

```
Select 
JSON_VALUE(JsonFile, '$.company.6Months.count') 
From dbo.Filestore

Msg 13607, Level 16, State 4, Line 3
JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '6' is found at position 10.
```

Comment: You should seriously rethink the attribute name. Most languages disallow names that start with numbers, not just T-SQL. Even *JavaScript* doesn't allow numbers at the start when you use dot notation

Comment: Check [Can I get a javascript object property name that starts with a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809790/can-i-get-a-javascript-object-property-name-that-starts-with-a-number). In MDN [Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) explains the differences between dot and bracket notation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use quotes in your `path` expression. As is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-path-expressions-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#PATH), if *the key name starts with a dollar sign or contains special characters such as spaces, surround it with quotes*.

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(JsonFile, '$."company.6Months.count"') 
FROM dbo.Filestore
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Zhorov, that solved it for me.

Comment: @Stephen you should consider changing that name. Even JavaScript would choke on `6Months` if you used dot notation, ie `myObject.6Months`